# JavaScript regexr replace string with html?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my code.

```
var input = "this is @renish profile";
var matches = input.replace(/(@\w*)/g,'<a href="http://example.com/users/profile/$1">$1</a>');
```

The output is:

```
this is <a href="http://example.com/users/profile/@renish">@renish</a> profile
```

This is print html code. How do I convert a tag from string?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can use jQuery.parseHTML() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: How are you currently adding that string to the page.... That is the $1,000 question.

Answer (score 2):

create a div, and use innerHTML.

```js
var input = "this is @renish profile";
var matches = input.replace(/(@\w*)/g,'<a href="http://example.com/users/profile/$1">$1</a>');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = matches;

document.body.appendChild(div)
```